# Predicate Logic - Difference between two english translated predicate statements

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I translated the statement "If at least one python program is correct, then all python programs are correct." Given the predicates $Python(x)$, $Correct(x)$, and the set of all programs $p$.

I have:

> $\exists x \in p, \forall y \in p, Python(x) \land Correct(x) \implies Python(y) \land Correct(y)$

However, the correct answer I was given/told was:

> $(\exists x \in p, Python(x) \land Correct(x)) \implies (\forall y \in p, Python(y) \implies Correct(y))$

I can see why the second is 100% correct in capturing the original statements meaning, but I cannot see intuitively why my original statement does not. Anybody have a good way to explain the difference for future reference? The only thing I can think of is that my statement CAN be vacuously true when $x$ is not a python program and correct...

Comment: I‘m a bit confused because the bottom one states: If there is a program that is a python program and correct then all programms are correct and python programms, how do we now the latter (that they also are python programms)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Translating your formal statement back into English reads like this:

> There exists a program such that if this program is a correct python program, then every program is a correct python program.

As you noticed yourself, this statement is trivially true if there exists a program which is not a python program or not correct. So, in particular, your statement is clearly true in our world, while the given statement clearly is not.

I want to note, however, that the "correct answer" seems to be wrong, too. Translating this statement back to English actually reads:

> If at least one python program is correct, then all programs are correct python programs.

I would rather translate the given statement as follows:

> $(\exists x \in p, Python(x) \land Correct(x)) \implies (\forall y \in p, Python(y) \implies Correct(y))$

Comment: I got the correct expression wrong, just changed it. It is indeed Python(y)⟹Correct(y) instead of Python(y) and Correct(y)

Comment: But why does my statement not capture the original meaning? Is "There exists a program such that if this program is a correct python program, then every program is a correct python program" not the same as "If at least one python program is correct, then all python programs are correct"?

Comment: @Curulian Because it's not "there exists a program such that..." but rather "IF there exists a program such that ___ THEN - - - ". Don't use commas to delimit quantifiers, their scope is very unclear when you do. Use parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

> $\exists x \in p, \forall y \in p, Python(x) \land Correct(x) \implies Python(y) \land Correct(y)$

As written, due to [precedence conventions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3908386/21813), your suggested sentence is technically is equivalent to $$\big(\exists x {\in} p \;\forall y {\in} p\; Px\big) \land Cx \implies Py \land Cy.$$

But I suppose you actually meant $$\exists x {\in} p \;\forall y {\in} p\; \big(Px \land Cx \implies Py \land Cy\big),\tag#$$ which is the [Prenex form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form#Implication) of (and thus equivalent to) $$\forall x {\in} p \;\big(Px \land Cx\big) \implies \forall y {\in} p\;\big( Py \land Cy\big),\tag#$$ which is clearly not equivalent to $$\exists x {\in} p \;\big(Px \land Cx\big) \implies \forall y {\in} p\;\big( Py \implies Cy\big),\tag✔$$ which is the correct answer.

[$(\#)$ is actually a first-order tautology (logically true)](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#%7E7x%7E6y(Px%7E1Cx%7E5Py%7E1Cy)), can be rewritten as $$\forall x {\in} p \;\big(Px \land Cx\big) \implies \forall x {\in} p\;\big( Px \land Cx\big),$$ and is literally read as “if every program is Python and correct, then every program is Python and correct”.

> However, the correct answer I was given/told was:
> $(\exists x \in p, Python(x) \land Correct(x)) \implies (\forall y \in p, Python(y) \implies Correct(y))$

This answer is actually also not correct, as it is technically equivalent to $$\big((\exists x {\in} p\;Px) \land Cx\big) \implies \big((\forall y {\in} p\; Py) \implies Cy\big),$$ which is not equivalent to $(✔).$