# There is an odd number between any two even numbers

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, logic-translation

> Write the complete mathematical logical expression of the following: there is an odd number between any two even numbers.

My attempt:

$E(x): x$ is even.
$O(x): x$ is odd.

$$∀m∀n∃k[(E(m) ∧ E(n) ∧ O(k)) ∧ (m < k < n)]$$

This looks like in English I'm saying: For all m and for all n there is a k where m is even, n is even, k is odd, and m is less than k is less than n, meaning that there is some odd number between any two even numbers.

Or, do I need to specify that n could be less than m as well?

**EDIT:** Attempt 2:

$$∀m∀n∃k[(E(m) ∧ E(n) ∧ O(k)) ∧ ((m < k < n) v (n < k < m))]$$

Comment: Yea good catch. Attempt 2 is good. A nitpick is that next time try to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: But neither attempt is good. Both attempts imply $\forall m\ \forall n[E(m)\land E(n)]$ (by conjunction elimination), which is wrong.

Comment: Consider changing the conjunction to $(E(m)\land E(n))\implies\exists k ...$

Comment: But the statement is wrong? For example, between 2 and 2 there is no odd number.

Answer (score 3):

> > there is an odd number between any two even numbers.

First, let's rearrange the sentence into a more logical ordering: $$\text{Given any two even numbers, there is some odd number between them.}$$ So: $$\forall (m,n){\in}\mathbb E^2,\;\exists k{\in}\mathbb O\,\Big(\text{$k$ is between $m$ and $n$}\Big)$$ But wait, this formalisation admits couples like $(2,2),(16,16),$ etc.! Assuming that the author actually means “two *distinct* even numbers” (in which case the given statement is true), we have to refine it (adopting the usual [precedence convention](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3908485/21813) to minimise my number of parentheses): $$∀m∀n \;\bigg(Em ∧ En ∧ m\ne n \to ∃k\: \Big(Ok ∧ (m < k < n \;\lor\;  n < k < m)\Big)\bigg).$$ Notice that I did not insist that the quantifiers all be lumped together in front; it's easier to make sense of the translation when they are placed at their natural locations. Finally, if the [prenex form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form) is preferred: $$∀m∀n∃k\; \bigg(Em ∧ En ∧ m\ne n \to Ok ∧ \big(m < k < n \;\lor\;  n < k < m\big)\bigg).$$ Do note that although it seems that I have simply pulled the quantifiers to the front, the actual algorithm for converting a logical formula to prenex form is a little less straightforward than this.

Alternatively, the previous formula can be rewritten without the conditional: $$∀m∀n∃k\; \bigg(¬Em ∨ ¬En ∨ m=n ∨ \Big( Ok ∧ \big(m < k < n \;\lor\;  n < k < m\big)\Big)\bigg).$$

*When formalising a statement (analogous to writing an essay in drafts), you don't have to do it in a single step, and the preliminary steps need not be fully correct.*

> Attempt 2: $$∀m∀n∃k[(E(m) ∧ E(n) ∧ O(k)) ∧ ((m < k < n) \;\lor\;   (n < k < m))]$$

This sentence is false: for $(m,n)=(1,2),$ there is **no** $k$ for which $$E(m) ∧ E(n) ∧ O(k) ∧ (m < k < n \;\lor\;  n < k < m)$$ is true.

Answer (score 0):

Let $E(x)$: $m$ is even

$O(x)$: $m$ is odd

where $x\in\mathbb N$.

Then, the statement is:

$\forall m,n\in\mathbb N, \exists k\in(m,n)$ s.t. $(E(m)\land E(n))\implies O(k)$